# How to use ECS credentials with AWS JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to access a **S3 Bucket** using the *AWS JS SDK* but without success.

I got a **task definition** that uses a **task role** called `Foo`. This task role as an attached **policy** to access to the S3 Bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bucket"
    }
  ]
}
```

It says in the [AWS Documentation about loading credentials from IAM roles for EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html) that I should configure my instance to use IAM roles. But I can't find anything about that in the AWS documentation.

I tried to define the `credentials` using the [`AWS.ECSCredentials class`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECSCredentials.html):

```
const options = {
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  region: bucketSettings.region,
  credentials: new AWS.ECSCredentials({
    httpOptions: { timeout: 5000 }, // 5 second timeout
    maxRetries: 10, // retry 10 times
    retryDelayOptions: { base: 200 }, // see AWS.Config for information
  })
};

this.s3Instance = new AWS.S3(options);
```

When I try to access a file in the S3 Bucket:

```
const document = await this.s3Instance
  .getObject({ Bucket: bucketSettings.name, Key: key })
  .promise();

return document;
```

I still got an

> Access Denied

Any idea what I'm missing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the policy to access the S3 Bucket (note the `/*` at the end of the resource):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Plus, the `credentials` option provided to the AWS SDK is not needed:

```
const options = {
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  region: bucketSettings.region,
};

this.s3Instance = new AWS.S3(options);
```

Comment: I am trying the same thing, however, when I leave the credentials out, I get an error that says "Missing credentials" and if I add the credentials, I get the error "ECSCredentials is not a constructor". Any advice ?