# How to use ECS task role credentials with AWS SDK in Angular4

Tags: angular, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I am using the aws-sdk for JS / nodejs to upload files in Angular4 to a S3 bucket.

The **upload works fine without any issues** if I specify my credentials (accesskeyId, accesskey) when creating the S3 client object.

## Issue

I am trying to use **ECSCredentials** because I do not want to expose my accesskeys anywhere in my code.

My application is running in a **ECS Container Instance** and is executed with an **ECS Task**.

I have created an ECS Task role in IAM and attached it to the Task via the Task Role inside my container definitions. (I followed this documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

Once the task is running, I am able to log into the container (via ssh) and check if the permissions is working via "curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI"

**This works 100% and outputs my credentials just like the example.**

However, I am having a very hard time trying to get this to work with aws-sdk.

In my Angular4 component, I add the SDK like so :

```
import { ECSCredentials, S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
```

I create my S3 object like so :

```
private _s3ClientConfig: S3.ClientConfiguration;
private _s3: S3;
```

and then create the instance like so :

```
this._s3ClientConfig = {
credentials: new ECSCredentials({
  httpOptions: { timeout: 5000 },
  maxRetries: 10,
  retryDelayOptions: { base: 200 }}),
region: this._awsConfig.s3BucketRegion,
sslEnabled: true
};

this._s3 = new S3(this._s3ClientConfig);
```

When I do this, I get the error :

```
ECSCredentials is not a constructor
```

I have also tried omitting the "credentials" part, however, then I get the error :

```
 Missing credentials in config
```

I have also tried creating the S3 client options as type S3.ClientConfiguration or just a normal object, same error persists.

I have followed instructions on another stack overflow question here : [How to use ECS credentials with AWS JS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634775/how-to-use-ecs-credentials-with-aws-js-sdk) , however, no luck, same problems and errors.